# Best practice for SquishIt in develop time

Tags: squishit

SquishIt could bundle the js files. But I don't want to bundle it in the develop time. What is your best practice? There are some methods as below:

1. Add a global property to indicate develop time or production time.
2. use #if DEBUG ... #end

Above methods is not perfect, Is there any configuration switch on SquishIt for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
<compilation debug="true">
    <!-- snip! -->
</compilation>
```

in your web.config squishit should skip bundling and render individual file tags into your page.